# WPF: Bind Command with Checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am pretty new to WPF and MVVM so this may be a very easy question. I have an app with a button and a checkbox. Once the button is clicked it runs a command that then runs a script. The checkbox is an option to view an internet browser as the script runs. I am wondering how I can pass in wheather the checkbox is checked or not once the button is selected. I changed some of the coding names to be more basic. Here is my Xaml:

```
<StackPanel Margin="10">
        <CheckBox Content="Option" IsChecked="True"  />
        <Button Height="20"
                Content="Run Script"
                Command="{Binding Script }"
                />
    </StackPanel>
```

And here is the the ViewModel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ICommand script{ get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        script = new RelayCommand(o => MainButtonClick());
    }

    private void MainButtonClick()
    {
        Program start = new Program();
        start.Begin();
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use a `CommandParameter`.

Comment: @dymanoid Yes a CommandParameter could work, assuming the `RelayCommand` class can handle Parameters. So OP might need to adjust their RelayCommand, IMO binding the `IsChecked` property to the ViewModel is easier, and also allows for more parameters down the road

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the `IsChecked` of the CheckBox to a property in the ViewModel. Something like this should work:

```xml
<CheckBox Content="Option" IsChecked="{Binding ShowBrowser}"  />
```

```cs
public bool ShowBrowser {get; set;}
```

You can then use the `ShowBrowser` property in your `MainButtonClick` method

Or you could use a Command Parameter as dymanoid pointed out in the comments. Like so:

```xml
<CheckBox Name="ShowBrowser" Content="Option" IsChecked="True"  />
<Button Height="20"
    Content="Run Script"
    Command="{Binding Script }"
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ShowBrowser, Path=IsChecked} 
    />
```

And then your Method would look like this:

```cs
private void MainButtonClick(bool showBrowser)
{
    Program start = new Program();
    start.Begin();
}
```

This is of course assuming your `RelayCommand` class can handle parameters

Comment: That was incredibly simple... thank you so much! I will mark this as the answer once the ten minutes are up. Thank you again!